# Is there a filter to block or low-light questions from people whose profile names start with user and end with a series of numbers?

Tags: support

Is there a filter that blocks or low-lights questions from people whose user accounts start with `user` and end with a series of numbers?

Comment: What for? Or are you just trying to block all new users?

Comment: On stackoverflow.com such profiles are a low quality question indicator. New users who take the time to self-identify in some way using their profile name seem to make more of an effort to ask site appropriate questions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "low-light"? Presumably the opposite of "highlight". Are you referring to functionality you've seen before on SE, or are you proposing something new?

Comment: By low-lighting I mean the way that questions appear when they match my ignored tags. They're are the list, readable, but they are partially masked. And just to be clear I am just asking if such functionality exists. It was not a feature request.

Comment: Not sure why this question is getting down votes. I presume down voters think it would be a bad idea to have such a feature. I was just asking if it existed.

Comment: That's pretty much right, Rob. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences. Kinda weird, but.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Thanks for pointing that out. Until then, I was kinda thinking I'd never ask a question on Meta again :-)

Comment: Fun fact: the [top four most downvoted answers on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?page=1738&tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer) (-172!) were posted by Stack Overflow's co-founder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. No such filter exists and we currently have no plans to add one.

If you really must have this, you could write up a browser extension to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't.

I can see where you're coming from; sort of. We've all come across those who register, ask just one question and then little else, but in effect, a username that starts with `user` is not reflective of either:

- A users status or experience in using an SE website.
- The amount of time they have been a member.
- The quality of questions or answers they pose.
- The value of their participation.

There are lots of users, who aren't concerned or care about their username and those who don't wish to be identified in any way.

After doing a quick search in light of your question, I quickly discovered what I know already - there are many users who have far more rep than I do, but who haven't changed their username and probably have no wish to. Therefore, you can't use such a filter with any accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, "such profiles" are indicators that the user has not changed their username yet. You started with a `userXXXXXXX` username as well. So did I. Mine was `user1131435`, until I changed it.

And, as far as I'm aware, the only reason a question's coloring becomes lighter is if it's on your blocked tags list.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I was ever userXXXXXXXX, I was asked for a username when I signed up.

Comment: How long ago did you sign up?

Comment: 2 years, 8 months ago. I didn't originally login with OpenID IIRC, it was a form you could fill out with an email (when you asked a question) instead.

Comment: @Rich I imagine that's why. Hm.